# Why does implicit differentiation apply to circle equation and works ?!

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

The question is, why implicit differentiation applies to equations [ Because they're not functions ] 
As we know, we can apply derivation to the functions, and I know that in implicit differentiation we consider $y$ as a function of $x$, but what that function is?
I had also asked another question which didn't get a satisfying answer for it, it is also related to this matter.

[Why are we allowed to take the derivative of ellipse equation? [ Is there any geometric representation of it? ]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785978/geometric-intuition-of-partial-derivative-in-2d-space)

Please, please, please to infinity , don't give Wikipedia link of the theorems.I just wonder about those people who copy/paste the Wikipedia links, if Wikipedia was satisfying, I would have never asked my questions in here.

I will absolutely appreciate whoever gives enlightening piece of favor!

*As a side note, people around me, students, and TA's can't even understand the question.So, it has become really important for me to know the answer!

Comment: Why does something need to be a function in order for you to differentiate it? See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936206/why-does-implicit-differentiation-work-on-non-functions?rq=1

Comment: The short answer is that differentiation is local, and the circle is a function of $x$ locally, except at the left and rightmost points. This is also why even implicitly, the derivative at the left and rightmost points blows up.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that the question is not very clear.  But look, there is something simple going on here.  If we have an equation: $$\text{something} = \text{something else}$$

Then surely we also have the equation: $$\text{derivative}(\text{something}) = \text{derivative}(\text{something else})$$

So if you accept that we can differentiate *one* side of the equation, then you must accept that we can differentiate *both* sides and set them equal to one another.

Do you accept this?  You say that you understand that we treat $y$ as a function of $x$, but you ask *what* that function is.  This misses the point.  Implicit differentiation is useful precisely when we *don't* know exactly what function we're dealing with.  For example, suppose that I'm looking at this equation:

$$e^y \sin y = x^3 + x^x$$

Solving for $y$ would be a nightmare (if it were even possible).  But we can still obtain information about the *derivative* of $y$, just by differentiating both sides using the chain rule (do this; it's a good exercise).

In some cases, we may be able to find the slope of a curve at certain points without ever knowing a parameterization of the curve.

All of this hinges on whether or not we can think of $y$ in the above equation as a function of $x$.  So?  Can we?

(Note: MrSlunk just posted a link to a nice answer that discusses this final question in detail.)

Comment: Indeed, I knew this all, but if you think of $y$ as a function of $x$ in the circle equation, then you get $y=\sqrt {25-x^2}$ which only gives the upper half of the plane( half circle ) but in the implicit differentiation it works for the part under $x$ axis.Still not satisfied, but thanks for your reply.

Comment: @FreeMind See the link that MrSlunk provided.  This is a complicated question in general, but for your specific example, the problem is that you chose some particular $y$.  You could also have chosen $y= -\sqrt{25-x^2}$, which is a different function that also satisfies that equation.  For example, if you want to determine the slope at a point in the upper half of the circle, you would choose your $y$, and if you wanted to determine the slope at a point in the lower half, you would use my $y$.  But we don't need to pick a $y$ immediately, since differentiation is valid whichever $y$ we choose.